# Performance Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS vs 15.10

Tags: drivers, wine, performance, ram, cpu

I am running now on Windows 7, but i am thinking about going to Linux (Ubuntu), i have experiences only with debian (VPS) yet :) But i like Linux, so i would like to have Ubuntu as my primary desktop OS.

I know that Ubuntu 14 is more stable and has support to 2020 and Ubuntu 15 has much shorter support, but it has new features.

I would like to ask you about performance comparison of these distributions. Which has bigger performance, lower hardware usage (CPU, RAM,..), bigger 3D performance for example for gaming (Wine)

And the last question, does Ubuntu 15 have more drivers avaiable (or are releasing faster than on 14)? For example drivers for chipset, sound, lan...

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two Ubuntu editions :
Ubuntu 14.04.3 - kernel 3.19 | Ubuntu 15.10 - kernel 4.2

Performance depends on the hardware being in use.
There will be not a big difference to be experienced.
The general drivers support is not different as well !

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is only a few months away ... you can choose whatever fits more to your needs.
Ubuntu 14.04 is stable - Ubuntu 15.10 has more current software packages - both run pretty fine.

Comment: Thank you, i mean that hardware would be same on both OS, and as you said that Ubuntu 15.10 uses kernel 4.2, it should mean that it is faster no? Because newer versions of kernel should have better performance

Comment: @tomsk : Maybe it is a little bit faster because new kernels bring along many bug fixes and improvements, but the biggest improvement is reliability concerning overall hardware support ... anyway it is up to you ! :)

Comment: Could you write me at tomsk.slovak@gmail.com? I would like to hear your opinion on some things about ubuntu